# Can I create a String variable that will always be the newest nextLine() Scan?

Tags: java.util.scanner

Because creating a new String variable for the next line is only stored as the next line of whatever my printout is, is there a way for me to create a new String variable that will always be the newest nextLine()?  I want to do this so I don't have to keep making new Strings to collect each new line of input.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great user name ;-)  Your question is a little confusing. Can you please post some code?  It sounds like you are continuously creating string objects(?) instead of simply declaring a single string variable and overwriting its contents each time you assign the result of reading a line (but I admit that I don't totally understand your question, hence the request for code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, example below:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 

out.println("Enter something: "); //user enters "some"
String scanInfo = scan.NextLine();

out.println(scanInfo); //outputs "some"


out.println("Enter something: "); //user enters "thing"
scanInfo = scan.NextLine();

out.println(scanInfo); //outputs "thing"
```

Just make sure you know it is being rewritten every time so you will not be able to access it again. Also be careful with .nextLine and .nextInt (as you wont be able to save .nextInt to a string variable)

Another idea (not sure the exact implementation you are looking for) would be to use a stack, because then you can keep track of all of the scanned in information and can pop off the most recent scanned value